# why my checkboxes arent generated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following controller that calls view with template that generates a set of `checkboxes`

The controller / Action

```
    public class CompoundsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Compounds/
        testdbDBContext db = new testdbDBContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var comps = db.Compounds.Select(e => new CompoundModel { Id=e.Id, Code=e.Code, Name=e.Name, IsSelected = e.IsSelected }).ToList();

            return View(new ChemicalsVM { cModel = comps});
        }
}
```

The view

```
@model mvca1.Models.ChemicalsVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ChemicalsVM</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Chemicals")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.cModel)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cModel)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

the template is:

```
@model mvca1.Models.CompoundModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "rmplCompoundDB";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Code)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsSelected, (Model.IsSelected)? new {@checked="checked"}:null)
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name)
```

when i ran the code instead of generating `checkboxes` with labels it displays the id numbers (that should be hidden)

here is the video of what happens https://youtu.be/1Z2fwfBgyn8

why it does not display the `checkboxes` as expected?

UPDATE:

here is my `ChemicalsVM`

```
   public class ChemicalsVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public string DName { get; set; }

        public List<CompoundModel> cModel { get; set; }

        public ChemicalsVM()
        {
            cModel = new List<CompoundModel>();
        }

    }
```

here is the `CompoundModel` class

```
 public class CompoundModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your `EditorTemplate` needs to be in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and it needs to be named `CompoundModel.cshtml`

Comment: And the code for the checkbox should be just `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsSelected)` - if you want them to be selected, set the value of `IsSelected` to `true` in the controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i though i can place the template in teh controllers View folder?

Comment: Yes, it can also be in the `/Views/Compounds/EditorTemplates/` folder

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh quick check, does the subfolder must have the name EditorTemplates

Comment: Yes, it must be in the `...../EditorTemplates` subfolder

Comment: @StephenMuecke bravo it worked thanks mate!

Comment: @StephenMuecke please post as an answer if you'd like to receive merits for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html being rendered means the ViewEngine is not finding the `EditorTemplate`. The template must be named the same as the class (i.e. `CompoundModel.cshtml`) and be located in either the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` or `/Views/Compounds/EditorTemplates` folders.